# Encountering ChunkedEncodingError whilst scraping Reddit comments using PSAW

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I have been trying to scrape Reddit comment data using the PSAW wrapper for Pushshift, I am scraping daily data for 365 days for 24 assets from wallstreetbets. Tickers is a list of ticker symbols that I am gathering the data for.

```
dfc = []
for i in tickers:
start_date = int(dt.datetime(2020, 6, 29, 0,0,0).timestamp())
start_date2 = int(dt.datetime(2020, 6, 29, 23,59,59).timestamp())
end_date = int(dt.datetime(2021, 6, 25, 0,0,0).timestamp())

gen_init = api.search_comments(subreddit='wallstreetbets',q=i,limit=100000,after=start_date,before=start_date2)
df_init = pd.DataFrame([X.d_ for X in gen_init])
df_final = df_init[0:0]

while start_date < end_date:    
  gen_data = api.search_comments(subreddit='wallstreetbets',q=i,limit=100000,after=start_date,before=start_date2)
  df_inter = pd.DataFrame([X.d_ for X in gen_data])
  df_final = pd.concat([df_final,df_inter],axis=0)
  #df_final['created_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df_final['created_utc'],unit='s')
  df_final['asset'] = i[0]
  start_date  = start_date  + 86400
  start_date2 = start_date2 + 86400
  
dfc.append(df_final)
```

The code runs for a fairly long time and eventually encounters the following error sooner or later:

```
ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))
```

I am not too sure what to make of this or how to go about solving this problem

Comment: Hi bro. Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VahidGhafouri Unfortunately not :(